# Drop Oracle View IF Exist In Single Query For Liquibase Changelog

Tags: oracle, view, liquibase, oracle19c

I am working on creating a Liquibase changelog which drops pre-identified **views** from an Oracle 19c database.

Initially I created a `PL/SQL` block

```
  DECLARE
     dne_942    EXCEPTION;
     PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(dne_942, -942);
  BEGIN
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP VIEW viewName';
  EXCEPTION
     WHEN dne_942 THEN
        NULL; -- if it doesn't exist, do nothing .. no error, nothing .. ignore.
  END;
  /
```

ended up with error

```
; expected "OR, FORCE, VIEW, ALIAS, SEQUENCE, USER, TRIGGER, ROLE, SCHEMA, CONSTANT, DOMAIN, TYPE, DATATYPE, AGGREGATE, LINKED, MEMORY, CACHED, LOCAL, GLOBAL, TEMP, TEMPORARY, TABLE, PRIMARY, UNIQUE, HASH, SPATIAL, INDEX"; SQL statement:
```

Later find out that `H2 doesn't support PL/SQL blocks`.

I am trying to have a single statement for this

My Research and Few Points:

1. Oracle doesn't support `IF EXIST` for views
2. I do not want to skip execution using `dbms:!h2`

Comment: How are you running the script to create the views in the first place ? are you using `create view` or `create or replace force view` ?

Comment: You probably need to use `splitStatements=false` in Liquibase where your run your SQL script

Comment: @Roberto Create or replace.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I did that. No success.

Comment: Would you please share the changeset you have created?

Comment: Could you say why you want to drop if exists?  Could you just define the stored procedure and use runOnChange=true to update the stored procedure only when you want to change the stored procedure.  It would be helpful to know why you want to drop if exists.  Keep in mind some best practices: https://www.liquibase.org/get-started/best-practices. I would say in general, changesets should be ran as is, and not have conditional logic in the changeset.  I would not want want a changeset with drop based on condition that may have a chance to run in prod and destroy something by accident.